# volume in linear algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, derivatives, volume

I'm reading linear Algebra Done Right, and I don't understand why we come up with the formula inside the blue circuit. Someone please help me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The explanation is just given above your formula in the "blue circuit", together with $\sigma(x+y)\approx \sigma(x)+(\sigma'(x))(y)$. Here adding a fixed vector, namely $\sigma(x)$, produces another set with the same volume.

Comment: can you exlain it with more detail, break it into smallest pieces as possible ?

Comment: i understand that adding a fixed vector so volume still preserved but don't know what to do next

Comment: volume of σ(x+Γ)−σ(x) and volume of σ(x+Γ) are equal, volume of x+Γ and of Γ are equal. still doesn't mean volume of σ(Γ) and volume of σ(x+Γ) are equal, σ is just a function. and how the volume of σ(x+Γ)−σ(x) equal the volume of (σ′(x)(Γ)), Γ is a set and y is a vector. i still don't get it

Answer (score 1):

By definition of our set $\Gamma$ we have that if $\omega \in \Gamma$ then $\omega = x + y$ for some $y$ such that $\Vert y\Vert$ small.

In particular it follows by using the derivative as an approximation and the linearity of the derivative that
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\omega) &\approx \sigma(x) + \sigma'(x)(y) \\ &= \sigma(x) + \sigma'(x)(\omega-x) \\
&= \sigma(x) + \sigma'(x)\omega - \sigma'(x)x \\
&= \sigma(x)- \sigma'(x)x + \sigma'(x)\omega
\end{align*}

This means that the following sets are approximately the same
$$ \sigma(\Gamma) \approx \sigma( x) + \sigma'(x)x + \sigma'(x)(\Gamma)$$
Since adding constant vectors preserves volume we have

$$ \text{ Volume } \sigma(\Gamma) \approx \text{Volume }\sigma'(x)\Gamma$$